# How to create more than one object from user input in c# console app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, object, console, userinfo

in class File:

```
 class Employee {
   //PROPS
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public int Id {get; set;}
   //CONST.
   public Employee (string name, int id){
      Name = name;
      Id = id;
   }
```

in method class ( or in Main() ):

```
public void NewEmployee(string name, int id){

   Console.Write("ENTER NEW NAME: ");
   string new_employee = Console.ReadLine();
   Console.Write("ENTER ID: ");
   int employee_id = Console.ReadLine();

   Employee e = new Employee(new_employee, employee_id);
}
```

now it creates only one object I called it "e". but how to create more than one object one after the other by user?

Comment: Call your `NewEmployee`- method on a loop? By the way: the object is not really called `e`, that´s just the name of the reference to that object. There is no such thing as a name of an object, unless your class has some field or property called `Name`.

Comment: What do you want to do with the object? Currently you just throw it away after leaving the `NewEmployee`-method. I suppose you want to store it somewhere, e.g. in a list or whatever. In this case you should return that new object from your method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably do something along the lines of:

```
   List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();

   while (true) {
       Console.Write("ENTER NEW NAME: ");
       string new_employee = Console.ReadLine();
       if (new_employee == "")
           break;
       Console.Write("ENTER ID: ");
       int employee_id = Console.ReadLine();
       Employee e = new Employee(new_employee, employee_id);
       employees.Add(e);
    }
```

This will add new employees to a list until it gets an empty line for the name.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am a beginner, so pardon for the misunderstanding. what if i want now to retrieve data from some object, should  i do it from the List and not from my "e" obj ?

Comment: And if so, why use the obj at first place? why not insert user input straight into List ?

Comment: The thing you need to understand is that "e" is just a name, and the only reason I used it was to make it more like what you had written. It makes absolutely no difference here. "e = new Employee(); employees.Add(e);" basically means "Make a new Employee object -- let's call it e. Now put e on the list.", and "employees.Add(new Employee())" means "Make a new employee and put it on the list". These result in exactly the same compiled code.